# Получение польвательского ввода в ruby

Tags: ruby, ввод

*На вход подается число. Нужно считать его и вывести это число возведенное в квадрат.*
**Sample Input:**
6
**Sample Output:**
36

```
puts "6**2"
num = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "36"
```

Comment: Чем помочь, что не получается?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
x = gets.chomp()
res = x.to_i ** 2
puts (res)
```